# integrate rust/wasm with sqlite

Tags: sqlite, rust, webassembly

[sql.js](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/sqlite-wasm-in-the-browser-backed-by-the-origin-private-file-system/) compiles sqlite into a WASM module which can be called from javascript. However I want to call sqlite from another WASM module (built in Rust). What is the most optimized way to do it? I believe using the javascript layer as a bridge will not provide good performance. Should I somehow build sqlite together with my Rust code? Or is there an optimized way for two WASM modules to call each other without js glue?